# How to sort SharePoint search result by relevance and by modified date.?

Tags: 2013, search-results, sharepoint-on-prem

here I am trying to sort Sp search result by relevance and by modified date.for that i tried to add **Add sort level** in web parts properties as like below snap.but that is not working as i want.is there any other solution for this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The out of the boxen solution is to use the search resultat web parts sort field as per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sorting-search-results-in-sharepoint

Comment: the link you suggest does not show you how to do it.